# get_product_from_item() error with woocommerce_email_attachments hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to attach a pdf to an order response where the pdf is in the form "sku.pdf" using this code;

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'woocommerce_attachments_filter', 10, 3 );

function woocommerce_attachments_filter ( $attachments, $status , $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

     if (! $sent_to_admin ) { 

            $order_items = $order->get_items();

            foreach ($order_items as $item) { // loop through order items

              $_product = $item->get_product_from_item($item);
              $sku =  $_product->get_sku();

              $pdf_download = 'downloads/'.$sku.'.pdf'; 
              $attachments[] = $pdf_download;
              //$joining_instructions = 'downloads/W611.pdf'; 
              //$attachments[] = $joining_instructions;
            }
     }

return $attachments; 
}
```

Unfortunately it's throwing the error "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'" - apparently from the line `$_product = $item->get_product_from_item($item);`

Where am I going wrong?

(the commented lines are as far as I got successfully, ie the attachment code works)

Comment: There is, also something I don't understand about the pdf path. The downloads directory is at the root of the web server. so `/downloads/W611.pdf` is the correct path. If I do this I get an empty pdf. if I remove the intial slash thus `downloads/W611.pdf` the pdf is delivered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **`get_product_from_item()`**, as you can get easily and directly the product id, you can use **`wc_get_product()`** to get an instance of the $product object…

Here is your functional code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'woocommerce_attachments_filter', 10, 4 );
function woocommerce_attachments_filter ( $attachments, $status , $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

    if (! $sent_to_admin ) { 

        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) { // loop through order items

            $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
            $sku =  $product->get_sku();

            $pdf_download = 'downloads/'.$sku.'.pdf'; 
            $attachments[] = $pdf_download;
            //$joining_instructions = 'downloads/W611.pdf'; 
            //$attachments[] = $joining_instructions;
        }
    } 
    return $attachments; 
}
```

Also in your in `add_action()`, you need to put the correct numbers of arguments which are 4 here. If not, `$sent_to_admin` could be ignored or you could have some errors or bugs…

Comment: sorry ! forgot. It was a case of "teach him to fish...". (I was gone fishing ;-)